# Pass data from Node server to React from 3rd party API

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to make a request to 3rd party API, and then show it to the user on the website.  I am using Gatsby and Node.js. But I have some problem passing data from server to client.

This code is responsible for making a request to the server :

```
import React from "react"
import axios from "axios"

const Test = () => {

  const getDataFromServer = async () => {
    try {
      const resp = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/data")
      console.log("From frontend:" + resp.data)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={getDataFromServer}>Get Data</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Test
```

And here code responsible to make request to 3rd party API from Node:

```
require("dotenv").config()
const morgan = require("morgan")
const axios = require("axios")
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors")
const dataRoutes = require("./routes/dataRoute")
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use("/api", dataRoutes)
app.use(morgan("dev"))

const api = `${process.env.GATSBY_API_URL}?key=${process.env.GATSBY_API_KEY}&scope=jobPost&fields=name,ingress,startDate,endDate,logo`
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: api,
})

app.get("/data", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.get("/<path>")
    return response.data
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
})
app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("server is listening on port 8080")
})
```

I retrieve data from API but when I want to pass it to a client then nothing happening.

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Have you tried just logging resp, instead of resp.data?

Comment: I don't see any `res.send()` in your route handler.

Comment: Where should I add it ?

Comment: Add `res.send(response.data);` just after `await axiosInstance`